# Is selecting some of the sets such that their intersection is of size k NP-hard?

Tags: np-complete, np-hard

Given collection of sets S1,...,Sn and a positive number k. Is the problem of selecting some of the sets such that their intersection is of size k NP-hard?

So far, I tend to believe it is so I tried to find a reduction (unsuccessful so far),
I have tried is to replace intersection by union (which is equivalent if we take the complementary sets).

I've also tried to dualize the problem and view a values as representing sets where they appear (unfortunately this transformed problem is not equivalent [Is this problem NP-hard? select k sets from a collection of sets such that each selected set has an empty intersection with the non selected ones](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/70450/is-this-problem-np-hard-select-k-sets-from-a-collection-of-sets-such-that-each))

I don't know if this problem is of interest for the reduction but it is the closest hard one I've found
http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~eduardo/publications/ipl12.pdf

Comment: Equivalently: given sets $T_1,\dots,T_n$ and a positive number $k'$, select some of the sets so that their union is of size $k'$.  (The equivalence is obtained by taking $T_i = \overline{S_i}$ and $k'=m-k$, where $m$ is the number of elements in the universe, i.e., the cardinality of $S_1 \cup \dots \cup S_n$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you suggested, the problem is equivalent to selecting sets with union of given size $k$. It is not easier than selecting **given numbers** (say, $m$) of sets with union of given size $k$, since we could add different auxiliary elements $a_S^{(0)},\ldots,a_S^{(n)}$ to each set $S$ and ask for a union of size $m(n+1)+k$, where $n$ is the size of the original universe. Now it is not hard to show the later problem is NP-hard because of a reduction from X3C (exact cover by 3-sets).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see how the reduction would work because in my problem I don't have the restriction "every element of X occurs in exactly one member of C’ "? In my problem you could well select all the sets to cover the universe.

Comment: @user3020699 Suppose in X3C the size of the universe is $n=3q$, then it's the same as selecting $q$ 3-sets  with union of size $n$.

Comment: but my problem does not constraint the number of sets to select, it only constraints k = the size of the union. So if you ask to cover the universe {1,...,n}, my problem can select all the sets as a solution.

Comment: @user3020699 That's exactly what my answer tried to tell.

Comment: So you agree that the reduction does not work (you can't solve X3C using my problem because the selected do not guarantee  "every element of universe occurs in exactly one member of selected sets") or do you maintain it works and I missed your point?

Comment: @user3020699 I'm not sure if you read my post carefully. The reduction is X3C -> 'selecting $m$ sets with union of size $k$' ->  'selecting sets with union of size $k$'.

Comment: Consider the following X3C instance:
Suppose universe  is {1,2,3,4,5,6} |X|=6=3*2.
The candidate sets are {{1,2,3},{2,4,5},{2,5,6}}.
You reduce it to our problem and ask for a union of size 6.
The answer is Yes, you can select the three sets.
But selecting the three sets is not a solution to the X3C problem (as there is not solution on this example).

Comment: @user3020699 The instance is selecting 2 sets with union of size 6. So it further reduces to select from {{1,2,3,a0,...,a6},{2,4,5,b0,...,b6},{2,5,6,c0,...,c6}} for a union of size 20.

Comment: Ok now it becomes more clear: you choose a0,...,a6,b0,...,b6,c0,...c6 arbitrarily all different and also all different from the universe. Very smart!