# Finding $l$ subsets such that their intersection has less or equal than $k$ elements NP-complete or in P?

Tags: time-complexity, np-complete, reductions, polynomial-time-reductions

> I have a set $M$, subsets $L_1,...,L_m$ and natural numbers $k,l\leq m$.
>
> **The problem is:**
>
> Are there $l$ unique indices $1\leq i_1,...,i_l\leq m$, such that
>
> $\hspace{5cm}\left|\bigcap_{j=1}^{l} L_{i_{j}}\right| \leq k$

Now my question is whether this problem is $NP$-complete or not. What irritates me is the two constraints $l$ and $k$ because the NP-complete problems that were conceptually close to it that I took a look on (set cover, vertex cover) only have one constraint respectively that also appears in this problem.

I then tried to write a polynomial time algorithm that looks at which of the sets $L_1,...,L_m$ share more than $k$ elements with other sets but even if all sets would share more than $k$ elements with other this wouldn't mean that their intersection has more than $k$ elements...

This [question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/70500/is-selecting-some-of-the-sets-such-that-their-intersection-is-of-size-k-np-hard) kind of comes close but in it there is no restriction on the amount of subsets to use and the size of the intersection should be exactly $k$, but maybe this could be useful anyways.

Can somebody further enlighten me ?